# capture all screen output of gdrive

Tags: bash, google-drive-api, screen-capture

I have a Debian machine and a google drive sync tool gdrive
https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#traversal-depth

Google sync works fine, but the command syncs only when executed from prompt. So I created a sync script which is run in cron

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

cd /media/hdd/google_drive

date=`date +'%Y%m%d'`

echo "--- "$date" ---" >> /var/log/drive_sync.log

drive pull -no-prompt >> /var/log/drive_sync.log
```

and teh script works ok, except for one problem. it logs only a few of the commands output. Here is the example of the log file.

```
--- 20161109 ---
Resolving...
--- 20161110 ---
Resolving...
--- 20161111 ---
Resolving...
--- 20161112 ---
Resolving...
Everything is up-to-date.
--- 20161113 ---
Resolving...
Everything is up-to-date.
--- 20161114 ---
Resolving...
Everything is up-to-date.
--- 20161115 ---
Resolving...
Everything is up-to-date.
--- 20161116 ---
Resolving...
Everything is up-to-date.
```

and the problem is it doesn't log the following information when run from prompt.

```
user@name-pc:~/google_drive $ drive pull -no-prompt
Resolving...
+ /#transfer/test.txt
M /documents/downloads.xlsx
Addition count 1
Modification count 1 src: 10.96KB dest: 10.96KB
```

So you see that the information about the sync files does not end up in the log, only the "Resolving.." line ends up in the log, why doesn't the file count or the lines "+ /#transfer/test.txt" and "M /documents/downloads.xlsx".

So my question is why doesn't the output redirect work and redirect all of the text on screen to the file, but only the lines i showed you in the log.

Any advice on how to log all of the info output of the command would help.
I tried various stderr and stdout redirects, the tee command but never has the entire output ended up in the log file.

Comment: You're only capturing STDOUT. The rest of the program output is probably going to STDERR.

Comment: hy, i will quote myself "I tried various stderr and stdout redirects, the tee command but never has the entire output ended up in the log file".

i have tried
drive pull -no-prompt >> /var/log/drive_sync.log 2>&1
and
drive pull -no-prompt  &>> /var/log/drive_sync.log
and other varieties of redirects and still nothing 

so can you see if i did something wrong with the redirects?

Comment: the answer was script command:
script -q -c "drive pull --no-prompt" -a /var/log/drive_sync.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was script command:

```
script -q -c "drive pull --no-prompt" -a /var/log/drive_sync.log
```